# Access to R Column not defined

Tags: r

I have a very simple script:

```
u2 <- 1:10
usq2 <- u2 * u2
m2 <- cbind(u2,usq2)
df2 <- as.data.frame(m2)
```

str(df2) shows two columns u2 and usq2

How come I have access to df2$usq also? The output is the same as df2$usq2! I cleared my environment before executing this script.

Answer (score 2):

The dollar operator supports partial matching. `df2$usq` just returns `df2$usq2`. In fact, so will `df2$us`:

```r
df2$us
#>  [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

If you read the docs for the extraction operators (see `?'$'`) you will see:

> "...the default behaviour is to use partial matching only when extracting from recursive objects (except environments) by `$`. Even in that case, warnings can be switched on by options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE)."

Partial matching means that you only need to type enough letters to get a unique match with the names in the object you are subsetting:

```r
l <- list(ab = 1, b1 = 2, b2 = 3)

l$a
#> [1] 1
```

If there is any ambiguity, you get `NULL`:

```r
l$b
#> NULL
```

In your exsmple, both names start with a "u", so `df2$u` is `NULL`, but `df2$us` only matches with `df2$usq2`, so that is what is returned.